# error inside initiate block : use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#

can i give the instance name inside the initiation block . i am getting the error while using the following code. "use of unassigned local variable"

**Code Block**

```
Item item = new Item()
{
   Qty1 = item.Qty1 + item.Qty2
}
```

Comment: no its not valid, you are referencing a variable that is to not yet declared `item`

Comment: Make sure you declare the qty1 & qty2 variables with value types before assign them (e.g. int).

Comment: @HammadNasir have you tried and of the given answers?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an Item class:

```
public class Item
{
    // use constructor
    public Item()
    {
        // set your default values here
        this.Qty1 = 0; // example
        this.Qty2 = 0;
    }

    // declare both quantity item properties here (including nullables)
    public int Qty1 { get; set; }
    public int Qty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then, access property inside the class, assume the values had been set:

```
Item item = new Item()
{
    Qty1 = item.Qty1 + item.Qty2
}
```

To prevent NullReferenceException, you need to declare `int` as `int?` when assigning Qty1 inside instantiation block.

**Edit**: I see OP may need so-called multiple constructors, one with empty parameter for assigning default values and one for perform addition to Qty1 property:

```
public Item(int Qty1, int Qty2) : this()
{
    this.Qty1 = Qty1 + Qty2;
}
```

and call it:

```
Item item = new Item(Qty1, Qty2); // assume Qty1 & Qty2 are method parameters here
```

CMIIW.